# Notepad++ Regex - Find multiple characters and replace them with one character

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a file with +20K lines and some strings have this structure:

```
,"/d/s/aaa.jpg","/e/_/bbb.jpg","/_/2/bbb.jpg" ....
```

and I want to replace them with:

```
,"/aaa.jpg", "/bbb.jpg","/bbb.jpg" ...
```

Can some one provide me a regex expression that will find those 5 leading characters and replace them with "/"?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

Find what: `/[^/]+/[^/]+(/[^/]+\.jpg)`
Replace with: `$1`

Comment: It matches exactly the strings I want, but it replaces them with "$1"

Comment: Ok I found the solution. Replace with should be: \1.
Thank You very much M42

Comment: @user1891628: It's because you have an old version of NPP.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

The following:

```
\"\/[^/]+\/[^/]+\/
```

will match the `"/d/s/` or `"/e/_/` part of a string. You can test it here: http://regexpal.com/

Make sure to replace it with:

```
"/
```

to do more you would need capture groups (i.e. capturing some parts of the regex to reuse that in the substitution or manipulate it somehow)

Comment: The replace is perfect but it targets other strings on the file.

Comment: It is a csv file. As i could see a string of
`"SKU00000000000000612-6 1/2-Basic-Limegreen","0","Limegreen","Disabled","8.0%","No"`
it replaces with
`"SKU00000000000000612-6 1/2-Basic-Limegreen","","","","",""`